# How to stop eclipse to redownload the plugin from repository for a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, m2e

I am importing an existing project into my eclipse workspace. I am using Maven 2.2.0, and Eclipse Juno. I could build project successfully using mvn command prompt.

But unable to import the project as eclipse could not build the project.Eclipse is trying to again download from repository. What If we stop eclipse to download the resources again from  repository.

I thought I would add `Windows--->Preferences-->Maven--Archetype--Add local catalog`

I understood that we have `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` catalogu file. But to my surprise I cannot find it.

Please suggest me if I am proceeding with correct way or not.

If its correct way, how do I set local archetype.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Might be off topic: Are you able to uplift to Maven 3? The m2e plugin for eclipse comes with a built in copy of Maven 3.0.4. In the past I ran into trouble trying to build Maven 2 projects using it... (could be anecdotal though)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the mvn plugin and import the mvn project as such. Alternatively, you can eclipsify the mvn project using the goal eclipse:eclipse (with the mvn command line).

In mvn itself you could set the pluginRepo to updatePolicy NEVER temporarily, if you still have issues with Eclipse. I think Eclipse uses the same settings for importing mvn projects.

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

I personally never was happy with Eclipse's mvn integration. Have you tried IntelliJ?